# Apache James: eval: /opt/james/bin/./wrapper-linux-x86-32: not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email-server, unix

I'm setting up a James server for the first time. I'm using 3.0-beta4. After I copied the binaries to /opt, I tried running it:

```
neonorb@neonorb /opt/james/bin
 % ./james start
Starting Apache James Server App...
./james: 1: eval: /opt/james/bin/./wrapper-linux-x86-32: not found
```

I'm running Ubuntu 15 64bit. I checked, and that file does exist.

Comment: Assuming `/opt/james/bin/wrapper-linux-x86-32` is a shell script, what does `sh -x /opt/james/bin/wrapper-linux-x86-32` show?  (This should run that shell script in a "verbose" mode, which hopefully will indicate/provide more information on the source of the "not found" error.)

Comment: /opt/james/bin/wrapper-linux-x86-32: 1: /opt/james/bin/wrapper-linux-x86-32: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a bash script, more like an executable. Editing with nano, it's a bunch of '?' and escaped letters. It starts with "^?ELF^A^A^A........" though.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps it's a binary format that doesn't match your machine...

Answer (score 6):

A possible reason is that the prerequisite libc6 is not OK in your system. Use

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libc6-dev-i386
```

and then

```
$ sudo ./james start
```

will run